# Why cant the loop be terminated in my code?

Tags: c

This a reverse string code but the loop cant be terminated and keeps taking input

How can I terminate it

[image]

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <string.h>
 #define len 100
 int main() {
   char str[len];
   int i;
   do {
     gets(str);
     for (i = (strlen(str) - 1); i > -1; i--) {
       printf("%c", str[i]);
     }
     printf("\n");
   } while (str[0] != '\0');
   return 0;
```

Comment: You should check the return value of `gets`. If it fails, `str` will be unaffected, so not null

Comment: can you please elaborate more?

Comment: already tried it but got the same error

Comment: also the same result

Comment: my instructor told me  its something before the gets statement

Comment: Don't post images of text

Comment: `str[0]` is the first item of the string. It will never be `\0` = the end of string string, in case you actually entered something.

Comment: how to solve this?

Comment: Use: `while (gets(str))`

Comment: Don't use `gets`

Comment: while (gets(str)) didnt work

Comment: [Your code works](https://wandbox.org/permlink/slcRRGAUc0TdmU00) (correctly stops after entering blank line) after adding `}` at the end of code. Please post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

add str[0]='\0'; before gets and its done. this is because making a loop termination and to get out of the loop after clicking enter.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define len 100
int main() {
   char str[len];
   int i,lenh;
   do{
       str[0]='\0';
       gets(str);
       lenh=strlen(str);
       for(i=lenh-1;i>=0;i--)
          {
             printf("%c",str[i]);
          }
      printf("\n");
      }while(str[0]!='\0');
      return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

now, there are a few points (answer code below)

1. Basically, you are printing hand-to-hand with input, while the question states of a multi line input. So, first you have to take all the inputs and then output will be shown.
2. Your original code does not keep taking input as you have said. Question says the last string is empty string. You press enter in empty string, your above code will terminate.

**Remember Last Input String Should be Empty, that's termination condition**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
    char str[100];
    char stringArray[50][100]={0};
    int k,m,count=0,i=0,j=0;
    do {
        fgets(str,100,stdin);
        k=strlen(str);
        for(m=0;m<k-1;m++){
            stringArray[count][k-m-2]=str[m];
        }
        count++;
    }
    while (str[0] != '\n');

    for(i=0; i<count; i++){
        for(j=0;stringArray[i][j]!=0;j++){
            printf("%c",stringArray[i][j]);
        }
        if(i<count-1){
            printf("\n");}
    }
    return 0;
}
```

sample input

```
Hello team Loop
Welcome
```

sample output

```
pooL maet olleH
emocleW
```